# npm install error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, npm-install

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'install',
1 verbose cli   'react-bootstrap',
1 verbose cli   'bootstrap'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v12.17.0
4 verbose npm-session 4004d1d4d37ac517
5 silly install loadCurrentTree
6 silly install readLocalPackageData
7 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/react-bootstrap 521ms
8 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for react-bootstrap@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"requirejs":"~2.1.9"'
9 http fetch GET 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/bootstrap 521ms
10 silly fetchPackageMetaData error for bootstrap@latest Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...7bc2df7ec608869c9c8",'
11 timing stage:rollbackFailedOptional Completed in 0ms
12 timing stage:runTopLevelLifecycles Completed in 3560ms
13 verbose stack SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"requirejs":"~2.1.9"'
13 verbose stack     at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
13 verbose stack     at parseJson (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\json-parse-better-errors\index.js:7:17)
13 verbose stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-fetch-npm\src\body.js:96:50
13 verbose stack     at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:97:5)
14 verbose cwd D:\Talk2Tutor\material-kit-react-master
15 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
16 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "react-bootstrap" "bootstrap"
17 verbose node v12.17.0
18 verbose npm  v6.14.4
19 error Unexpected end of JSON input while parsing near '...,"requirejs":"~2.1.9"'
20 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

I got above error while running npm i react-bootstrap bootstrap. After the error occurred, I tried **npm cache clean --force** but it didn't resolve my problem. Then I **reinstalled node** and tried to install dependencies but I still get an error and installation is failed. Any one fixed this error. I tried all the things mentioned in the related question. But it didn't solve my problem. I use node v12.17.0 and npm 6.14.4.

Comment: Please share package.json

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upgrade npm using [npm-windows-upgrade](https://github.com/felixrieseberg/npm-windows-upgrade) solved the issue.

Answer (score 9):

I tried by executing command `npm cache clean --force`  and then executed the command that caused this error and it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

After running the command **npm cache clean --force** . You need to remove the **package-lock.json** file. This worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

[Popper.js](https://popper.js.org/) is required if you're using Bootstrap JS. Check the [docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/introduction/#js)

Comment: This is an example of the error. However, every npm install I got this kind of error.

Comment: Could you share your `package.json`

Comment: None of this worked for me. Any other suggestion?